# Why my transfer function keep turn back in to 'logsig'?

Tags: matlab, neural-network, pattern-recognition

I try to build a basic feedforward system using patternnet command that can recognise the data from MNIST dataset. Here is my code

```
one = [1];
one = repelem(one,100);
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Create Neural network%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
nn = patternnet([100 100]);
nn.numInputs = 1;
nn.inputs{1}.size = 784;
nn.layers{1}.transferFcn = 'logsig';
nn.layers{2}.transferFcn = 'logsig';
nn.layers{3}.transferFcn = 'softmax';
nn.trainFcn = 'trainscg';
net.divideParam.trainRatio = 70/100;
net.divideParam.valRatio = 15/100;
net.divideParam.testRatio = 15/100;
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Dealing with data%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

mnist_in = csvread('mnist_train_100.csv');
mnist_test_in = csvread('mnist_test_10.csv');
[i,j] = size(mnist_in);
data_in = mnist_in(:,2:785);
data_in = data_in';
target_in = mnist_in(:,1);
target_in = target_in';
nn = train(nn,data_in,target_in);
```

The problem is when I build this system the transfer function in output layer is set to softmax function. Somehow when I train my system the transfer function turn into 'logsig' function and it stay that way until I clear my workspace. I even try to set the transfer function of output layer in the code and program still find a way to change it to logsig. So is there anything I can do.

PS. I even try building this system using network() to make everything from scrath the program still change my tranfer function back from softmax to logsig.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see, there is a mistake in the `divideParam` parameter. You created the neural network as `nn` but the parameters that you changed is belong to a variable called `net`. Other than that, the creating neural network part is normal.

I think the problem lies in the data preparation part.
Your training target, the `target_in`, has the dimension of **1 x < Number of sample>**. Because of that, the `train` function replace 'softmax' with 'logsig' to fit with the output.

The output data for softmax should be in the form of **< Number of result> x < Number of sample>**

For example, the output is either 1,2 or 3. Then the output array shouldn't be

```
[1 2 1 3 3 1 ...]
```

but it should be

```
[1 0 1 0 0 1 ...;
 0 1 0 0 0 0 ...;
 0 0 0 1 1 0 ...]
```

Hope this helps.

EDIT: To turn the single array (**1 x < Number of sample>**) to the multiple array (**< Number of result> x < Number of sample>**), the data in the single array will be map with index. For example, 11 sample in a single array:

```
[-1    -5.5   4     0     3.3   4    -1     0     0     0    -1]
```

Checking all the unique number and sort it. Now every number has its index.

```
[-5.5  -1  0  3.3  4]   #index table
```

Going through the single array, for each number, place it in the right index. Basically, -1 will have index 2 so I will tick 1 in the second row at any column that -1 appear. Finally,

```
[ 0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0;
  1     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     1; #there are three -1 in the single array
  0     0     0     1     0     0     0     1     1     1     0;
  0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0;
  0     0     1     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0]
```

Here is the code for it:

```
idx = sort(unique(target_in));   
number_of_result = size(idx,2);
number_of_sample = size(target_in,2);
target_softmax = zeros(number_of_result,number_of_sample);
for i = 1:number_of_sample
  place = find(idx == target_in(i));  % find the index of the value
  target_softmax(place,i) = 1;        % tick 1 at the row
end
```

Comment: Thanks  a lot for the reply. I get the idea that you point out but If you don't mind can you tell me how to implement this idea since MNIST only give 1x<number of sample> as a target(I'm really lost here.).

Comment: Thanks a lot, This will help a lot.